# Virtual Network Editor and No Internet Access

Tags: vmware, windows-networking, virtual-network

I am trying to figure out the reason a Windows Server 2012 R2 virtual machine (VMWare Workstation 12.5) with Active Directory and DNS roles is complaining about *No Internet Access* (with an exclamation mark superimposed over the network icon in the Windows taskbar)... **even though I am able to access Internet**.

Using Virtual Network Editor, I enabled a `Virtual Network Adapter VMNet8` with following properties:

- Type: `NAT`
- Subnet address of `192.168.153.0`
- Gateway IP is set by default to `192.168.153.2`

In the VM, following properties are set on the single network adapter:

- Static IP of `192.168.153.15`
- subnet mask is `255.255.255.0`
- Default gateway is `192.168.153.2`
- Preferred DNS server is `127.0.0.1` (loopback address)
- Computer belongs to `contoso.local` domain (established by AD setup)

Under DNS settings, I set up a forwarder specifying IP address `192.168.153.2` (same as gateway IP of virtual network adapter `VMNet8`). Without this forwarder, name resolution does not work but I can still access the Internet using IP addresses (instead of FQDNs).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to forward your dns queries to gateway. Normally dns doesn't need forwarders for this situation. It has own records for local ip's and root hints for public ip's. Try this; forward your queries to 8.8.8.8 and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, I will try forwarding to Google's DNS as you suggested. The server I am setting up currently will be the domain controller and DNS server for a set of 5 servers in total, and I need all the servers to "talk" to one another in this isolated network, as well as reach the Internet (primarily for Windows updates and downloads). I used an online resource on Virtual Network Editor to set this up, and I am wondering why I see the "No Internet Access" indicator in my VM even though it appears to be working.